# Why does `answering help` not go to a new page in the edit window?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

When you try to [edit a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/117435/edit) you can get a page like this:

[image: :-(]

When you click on two of the links it opens upa new window (or tab, depending on your browser).

### But

When you click on `answering help` it opens up on the current page and you get the dialog: [image]

if you made any changes to the post.

Can we change that and make it so that link also opens up a new window (especially so we do not lose any changes we may have made to the post)?